# PyPy - SWIG - QuickFix mix

Tags: swig, quickfix, pypy, python-bindings

PyPy has some [compatibility limitations](http://pypy.org/compat.html), especially regarding the CPython C API.

I use [QuickFix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/) package which comes with precompiled SWIG bindings, and I'm considering using it with PyPy. As I am not fluent in C API and SWIG, my questions are:

- Does PyPy's C API compatibility limitations hinder work with SWIG? Could you explain why?
- Do I need to recompile the SWIG bindings to work specifically with PyPy? Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PyPy's C API compatibility layer would not work with SWIG. The main reason is that SWIG uses internal APIs and pokes into C structures without using APis. I guess SWIG could be fixed, but so far it has not been.

You would have to recompile it if it have worked, but it will not work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this. These days SWIG 4.0.2 and PyPy 7.3.7 or higher should play well together, it is worth a try.